# Is their any difference in PDO and MySQLi OOP?

Tags: php, oop, pdo, mysqli

Some examples...

> > ### MySQLi Connect
> >
> > ```
> > $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
> > ```

> > ### PDO Connect
> >
> > ```
> > $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", 'username', 'password');
> > ```

---

> > ### MySQLi Query
> >
> > ```
> > $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tabel (name) VALUES ('Peter')");
> > ```

> > ### PDO Query
> >
> > ```
> > $pdo->query("INSERT INTO tabel (name) VALUES ('Peter')");
> > ```

---

> > ### MySQLi Commit
> >
> > ```
> > $mysqli->commit();
> > ```

> > ### PDO Commit
> >
> > ```
> > $pdo->commit();
> > ```

So, what's actually the difference between [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) and [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)? To me it's quite the same when coding.. Any difference in speed/safety/etc. ?

Comment: see http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/11/difference-between-pdo-and-mysqli

Comment: First and foremost PDO doesn't just deal with MySQL, it supports other data objects

Answer (score 3):

Did you use google?
PHP.net offers a detailed page exactly about this topic.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

The differences are in the keys (comparing mysql functionality):

API supports non-blocking, asynchronous queries with mysqlnd:
**Mysqli yes, PDO no**

Supports all MySQL 5.1+ functionality: **Mysqli yes, PDO most**

API supports Multiple Statements: **Mysqli yes, PDO most**

But the **key difference between mysqli and PDO is**,
you can also use **PDO as an interface for SQLITE, Oracle, MS-SQL**.....
Mysqli only is for mysql

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference in PDO and MySQLi OOP?

Yes.
Just start actually using it and you will see.

In general, the only difference is that mysqli is a some sort of construction material for the higher level DB access library and shouldn't be used as is. While PDO is already sort of such a library and can be used as is.